# Laravel 5 how to show,hide div by dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, eloquent

> Problem is how to show and hide div by using dropdown onclick function.
>
> Blockquote Problem 2 is how to take getElementById("") by that style's number;

**This is my CSS and i want to display none all of my div**

```
<style>
#\1a{ display:none; }      // to 32...//
</style>
```

**This is my JS**

```
<script>
  function show(showid){
    document.getElementById("1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("2").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("3").style.display="none";
  }
</script>
```

**This is my dropdown**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" >
      Bla bla bla
  </button>
<ul id="test" name="form_select" class="dropdown-menu">
@foreach ($topics as $topic)
    <li><a href="#" onclick="show('')" style="font-size: 11px; padding:0px; line-height: 15px;">{{ $topic->title }}</a></li>
@endforeach
</ul>
</div>
```

**This is my div**

```
@foreach($collections as $collection)
<div id="{{ $collection->id }}">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <table border="1" style="width:100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><h4>Асуулт {{ $i++ }}.</h4><strong>{!! nl2br($question->question_text) !!}</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]" value="{{ $question->id }}"></td>
                </tr>
                    @foreach($question->options as $option)
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]" value="{{ $option->id }}">{{ $option->option }}</label>
                </td>
                </tr>
                    @endforeach
               </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the values of `$id` within the `@foreach($collections as $collection)`? The idea of the JavaScript code is to show a specific `div` and hide the rest? `$topic->id` has the same value of `$id`?

Comment: oh I'm sorry i forgot to edit. it's `$collection->id`

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? Please answer my other questions so I can fully understand what you need.

Comment: Yes I'm using bootstrap `version 3.7.7` Yes my javascript just hiding all div to show selected div. No its not the same. I edited my question please check. I'm changed to $collection->id its like 1 to 32. same as div's increment.

Comment: its $topic and $collection have same data?, can you post your controller

Comment: No its not same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dropdown:**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
        Bla bla bla
    </button>
    <ul id="test" name="form_select" class="dropdown-menu">
        @foreach ($topics as $topic)
            <li><a href="#" onclick="show({{ $loop->index }})" style="font-size: 11px; padding:0px; line-height: 15px;">{{ $topic->title }}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

We use [`$loop->index`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#the-loop-variable) as an incremental value. They must be equal to the `$collection->id`.

**DIVs:**

```
@foreach($collections as $collection)
    <div id="{{ $collection->id }}" class="topic hidden">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I added the class `topic` to identify all the `divs` (use whatever you want) and hide all of them with the [`hidden`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-show-hide) class. No need for the custom `CSS`.

**JavaScript:**

```
function show(id) {
    $('.topic').addClass('hidden');
    $('#' + id).removeClass('hidden');
}
```

The first line adds the class `hidden` to all the `divs` to hide them. The second one removes the `hidden` class for the specific `div`.
I used `jQuery` since you are using that library for `Bootstrap`.

> This all assumes that `$loop->index` and `$collection->id` have the same values. If not, you could try replacing `$collection->id` with `$loop->index`.